# Using DAO,DTO pattern as MVC

Tags: java, sql, model-view-controller, design-patterns, data-transfer-objects

```
    public abstract class BaseDAO<T extends BaseDTO> {

        public Integer create(T dto) {

        }
        public Integer update(T dto) {

        }
        public Integer delete(T dto) {

       }

     }


    public class JobDAO extends BaseDAO<JobDTO> {

        public JobDAO(Connection conn) {
            super(conn);
        }

        @Override
        public String getDBTableName() {
            return "JobTABLE";
        }
    }


    public class BaseDTO {

        protected Integer ID;

        public Integer getID() {
            return ID;
        }

        public void setID(Integer ID) {
            this.ID = ID;
        }
    }


    public class JobDTO extends BaseDTO {

        Integer employerID;
        //getter
        //setter

     }



   public class Job_GUI extends javax.swing.JFrame {
    //GUI properties
    }
```

I am trying to understand`Model, View, Controller` Convention and I want to apply`MVC` to above class structures I have which consist of Data Transfer and Access Objects. What I'm failing to understand,  is my structure above MVC? if so, what is the model? I'm guessing the DTO are themselves `Model`. Job_GUI is a `View` which I know already, but what is the `Controller`??

I want to directly write the `actionPerformed` codes in the Job_GUI itself, something like this snippet to create a job in db:

```
JobDAO jdao = new JobDAO(conn);
           //create object jobDTO to hold all form values to be passed to JobDAO
           final JobDTO jobDTO = new JobDTO();
           //populating JobDTO with values from form
           jobDTO.setEmployerID(id);
           jobDTO.setDescription(description.getText());
           jobDTO.setTitle(txtTitle.getText());
           jdao.create(jobDTO);
```

but should the above be in the `Job_GUI` class itself or somewhere else. If I were to insert the above snippet in `Job_GUI` am I moving away from the MVC convention as such? Where would you put the above snippet? The confusion lies in identifying which is the `controller` class out of all that I have if I were to use the `DTO`,`DAO` `Design Pattern` for database interaction.

Comment: Model is used by DAO classes. Controllers use DAO classes to decide which Views it should render. If you have lots of business rules, could be nice to have a business layer and make your controller to use it instead of DAO classes. On the other hand, business layer would be using the DAO classes. Between Controller and VIews, you could transfer DTO objects, or a ViewModel.

Comment: @FelipeOriani that didn't really answer my question although I appreciate your comment. I wanted to know If i'm following the MVC convention by adding the snippet of code into actionPerformed method in the Job_GUI class itself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
       JobDAO jdao = new JobDAO(conn);
       //create object jobDTO to hold all form values to be passed to JobDAO
       final JobDTO jobDTO = new JobDTO();
       //populating JobDTO with values from form
       jobDTO.setEmployerID(id);
       jobDTO.setDescription(description.getText());
       jobDTO.setTitle(txtTitle.getText());
       jdao.create(jobDTO);
```

In above code you basically doing job of **Controller** because you assigning values to your DTO and then calling create method of your DAO. **This is what Controller is supposed to do.** So you are right on this part except one small correction :

```
    JobDAO jdao = new JobDAO(conn);  //not preferable
    JobDAO jdao = new JobDAO();  //preferred inside Controller class
```

Will suggest you to keep connection specific code inside your DAO. Your Controller class shouldn't know about your DB connection. You can perform this inside your create/update/delete methods of DAO.

`DAO where you actually interact with DB is part of MODEL in MVC.`

Just keep in mind few things :

- MVC (architectural design pattern) stresses on separation of concern. So make sure that you have well defined classes for View, Controller and Model
- Your class names should convey which component it belongs to (BaseDAO etc)
- Controller controls View and Model. So your View and Model should not be aware of each other.

And as you mentioned that you are already clear with View. So i haven't put any explanation on that.